# What is the best ML algorithm for Customer-Agent Pairing?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I need to build a ML model to find a best customer care specialist who can best answer a customer question.

Please think Amazon as an example. If I feed my ML model with the question "what is the warranty for Macbook in UK?" , it should find the best customer care specialist who can best answer this warranty related question.

I have historical records, that I can use to train the ML model, where customer care specialists have answered customer questions. Each record contains customer questions, customer care specialist name, customer name, NPS score given to customer care specialist by customer, etc

Can you please help me by suggesting what ML algorithms I should start with? That would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to **Recommendation System**, where you want to recommend right customer, which can answer for the asked question.

Very similar to **Movie / Items / News Recommendation System**. For movies case, we have long list of movies, how to recommend best movies to the user on the basis of his interest and history.

There are many approach to solve this, notice that the data you have will be very sparse(Customer Agent Matrix, where each cell represent the score). You can use **SVD**, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217813/svd-recommandation-system/54219829#54219829) on using this.

There are some useful resources [first](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi74OKXs_TfAhUMXLwKHfejAS4QFjANegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.analyticsvidhya.com%2Fblog%2F2015%2F10%2Frecommendation-engines%2F&usg=AOvVaw3RnBIPsK2qnqm_aYDdMSTg), [second](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi74OKXs_TfAhUMXLwKHfejAS4QFjAOegQIDRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Frecombee-blog%2Fmachine-learning-for-recommender-systems-part-1-algorithms-evaluation-and-cold-start-6f696683d0ed&usg=AOvVaw2V2OaTvf9dsDIsdy6d3eVw) which you can refer.